# Invalid syntax for date type in view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a view which contains another multiple views joined by UNION ALL. Today I tried to run this query:

```
select distinct statistics_source, join_id,
                sum(media_publisher_budget_fact) as performance_product_budget_fact
from cs_fact.cs_fact_all cfa 
where statistics_date = '2023-10-20'
group by 1,2
```

And I got en error:

> SQL Error [22007]: ERROR: invalid syntax for date type: "1877"

`statistics_date` has a `date` type.

I tried to find this row which contains `1877` by this query (and many similar queries):

```
select distinct statistics_source, join_id,
                sum(media_publisher_budget_fact) as performance_product_budget_fact
from cs_fact.cs_fact_all cfa 
where statistics_date::text = '1877'
group by 1,2
```

But these queries don't work and also throws this error.
When I tried to run `select * from cs_fact.cs_fact_all` - no errors. When I remove `where statistics_date ...` from original query - query also completed.

How can I find this row and fix an error? This view has about 50 mil rows.

Comment: The problem is probably in your view definition, which performs a type cast that causes a runtime error with your data.

Comment: I've `COALESCE(cs_google_ads_ad_stat.statistics_date, '1970-01-01'::date) AS statistics_date` and so on in definition.

Comment: No need for `select distinct` here, the `group by` has already eliminated all duplicates. `select distinct` only makes people wonder what's going on?!?

Comment: Not that one. If you need help, add the view definition to the question. If the view uses other views, those could be the problem as well.

Comment: Search the base table not the view

Comment: Since 1877 doesn't like the day of the month or the month, it must be the year. You can EXTRACT() a year from the date and compare on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use EXTRACT() to get the year:

```
SELECT statistics_source
     , join_id
     , SUM(media_publisher_budget_fact) AS performance_product_budget_fact
FROM cs_fact.cs_fact_all cfa 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM statistics_date) = 1877
GROUP BY 1,2;
```